# What are the possible Microsoft graph subscription limitation for users calendars

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I need to subscribe 2500+ office 365 user calendars for event changes in a tenant.Subscriptions are used for synchronization purpose.what are the limitations of creating and maintaining subscriptions ?

I checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#azure-ad-resource-limitations) documentation and it says Maximum subscription quotas is 50,000 per app but i am not sure this is applied to my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The limitations you link are for Azure Active directory resources (changes happening on the user profile, groups etc...) and do not apply to Outlook resources (messages, events, calendars...).
The [following documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#contact-event-and-message-outlook) outlines the current limitations for Outlook resources, nothing mentions a limit in numbers of subscriptions. There might be internal limits on the number of subscriptions that can be created per mailbox.